# Can TinyMCE convert image pasted as data to an upload?

Tags: tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I am using TinyMCE 5.7 and it handles uploading images well. However when an image is pasted from the clipboard (ex: Snipping Tool) it gets pasted as data which is not desired. I can use the setting paste_data_images to block pasting data images but I would prefer that it convert the data into an upload request like normal image upload process. Is there a way to intercept the paste and do the upload? I am using both the image and paste plugins. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I figured out how to write my own paste function. First, in the TinyMCE config:

```
        setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('paste', function (e) {
            var imageBlob = retrieveImageFromClipboardAsBlob(e);
            if (!imageBlob) {
                return;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            uploadFile(imageBlob, function (response) {
                if ('location' in response) {
                    if (editor) {
                        // console.log('upload completed', response);
                        editor.insertContent('<img src="' + response.location + '" />');
                    } else {
                        console.log('Tinymce editor not found!');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Then the routine to decode the pasted info:

```
function retrieveImageFromClipboardAsBlob(pasteEvent) {
    if (pasteEvent.clipboardData === false) {
        return false;
    }

    var items = pasteEvent.clipboardData.items;

    if (items === undefined) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        // Only paste if image is only choice
        if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") === -1) {
            return false;
        }
        // Retrieve image on clipboard as blob
        var blob = items[i].getAsFile();

        // load image if there is a pasted image
        if (blob !== null) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
                // console.log('result', e.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
            return blob;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and a routine to upload the file

```
function uploadFile(file, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
        var percentComplete = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        console.log("Uploaded: " + percentComplete + "%");
    };

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            alert("Error! Upload failed " + xhr.response);
        }
        if (callback) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
        }
    };

    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert("Error! Upload failed. Can not connect to server.");
    };

    xhr.open("POST", "/upload/tinymce", true);
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Comment: Just one problem. It won't remove the already added image. Instead after complete server upload, it'll add one more image

Comment: use this event in the `init_instance_callback` function for v4.9. https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/advanced/events/#editorevents

Comment: Actually just tested and works with `setup` better.  `init_instance_callback` duplicates the image.